# Why padding of remainder of sector with zeros is not working with MASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, bootloader

i found a NASM command for padding remainder of boot sectors with zeros.

```
times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with zeros
```

it works well with NASM, but when i use this code with MASM then it shows error:

```
syntax error : integer
```

how can i implement same code for MASM compiler.
thanks

Comment: You could put a label at the start of your bootloader code like `start:` and then to do the padding you could do `byte 510 - ($ - start) dup (0)` followed by `dw 0aa55h`

Comment: But nasm shows how many bytes are lacking or exceeding in the same screen. but masm doesn't do so.

Comment: If you like NASM's features better, you could just keep using it for your MBR bootloader :P